# html disable text box when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to write Javascript to disable textbox if radio button is selected. I have 4 options for radio button and corresponding textbox. Even if I am selecting radio button 2, I am able to write values in radio 1 text and submit. So I want to add method on click or on change of radio button selection option. I have below Javascript function but it's not being called on event. Am I doing anything wrong. Why Javascript is not being called? Any help would be appreciated. I am new to Javascript.
[image]

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
               <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function EnableDisableTextBox() {
            alert("good")
            var chkYes = document.getElementById("search1");
            alert("Today's date is " chkYes);
            var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
            alert('java script')
            text1.disabled = chkYes.checked ? false : true;
            if (!text1.disabled) {
                text1.focus();
            }
        }
    </script>
    <form method="post">
        <br><br><br>
        <input type="radio"   onchange="EnableDisableTextBox()"   align="center" name="search" id="search1" value="" > By Keyword <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" for="search1"></input> <br>
        <input type="radio" align="center" name="search" id="search2" value="" id="search2" > In PostalCode <input type="text"  name="text2" id="text2" for="search2"></input><br>
        <input type="radio" align="center" name="search" id="search3" value="" id="search3" >Within<input type="number" name="text3" id="text3" for="search3" step="1" max="150" min="0">miles of me</input><br>
        <input type="radio" align="center" name="search" id="search4" value="Search4" id="search4" >In My PostalCode<br><br><br>
        <button name="button"  id="btn" onclick="window.location.href='/search/{{search}}'">Search</button>
    
           </form>
    
        </head>
    
    
    </html>
    
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change

```
            alert("Today's date is " chkYes);
```

to

```
           alert("Today's date is " ,chkYes);
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your code, you only bind onchange event on the first radio. you need to call the function on each radio button. Besides inside the **EnableDisableTextBox** function, only the first radion button is checked and only the first text box is being disabled.

I have create a fiddle for your reference in javascript and jquery:

[JAVASCRIPT](https://jsfiddle.net/aepf89so/)

[JQUERY](https://jsfiddle.net/qrb4gsc9/)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 function EnableDisableTextBox(e) {
   var text1 = document.getElementById('text1');
   var text2 = document.getElementById('text2');
   var text3 = document.getElementById('text3');
   var checkid = e.id;
   text1.disabled = true;
   text2.disabled = true;
   text3.disabled = true;

   if (checkid == 'search1') {
    text1.disabled = false;
   } else if (checkid == 'search2') {
    text2.disabled = false;
   } else if (checkid == 'search3') {
     text3.disabled = false;
   }
  }
```

**JQUERY**

```
  $(document).on('change', 'input[name="search"]', function() {
     var name = $(this).next().attr('id');
     $('input[type="text"],input[type="number"]').each(function(i, e) {
       if (name == $(e).attr('id')) {
         $(e).removeAttr('readonly');
       } else {
         $(e).val('');
         $(e).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
       }
     })
   })
```